# How to delete all but first two rows in a table (headers is the first row)

Tags: vba

I have a table that someone else will be pasting new data into weekly. The data being pasted each week will change in size by rows but not columns. I've automated the process up to the point where I keep the first row so formulas are not removed. This is all done through a button to which I have assigned the code. Now I need to delete the remaining rows of the table. Here is the code I have so far that works:

```
Sub ShrinkTable()
    Range("RDNPPD[[#Headers],[Follow Up by Corp Security]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RDNPPD").ListRows(ActiveCell.Row - 
    1).Range.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select    
End Sub

Sub DeleteRows()
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(2).Delete
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(2).Delete
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(2).Delete
    Range("RDNPPD[[#Headers],[Follow Up by Corp Security]]").Select
End Sub
```

RE: Sub DeleteRows() - I recorded a macro and the first line of code repeats for as many rows in the table that get deleted, which will change with each use thus will not work. The first row to be deleted will always remain the same: row 5. It's the last row that the code needs to account for being dynamic.

How do I delete the selection for a dynamic environment? Much thanks!

Comment: [VBA Delete Range Shift in Excel Explained with Examples](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/range/m/delete/)

Comment: Or [Clear Cells in Excel Range Worksheet using VBA](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/clear-cells-data-range-worksheet/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This duplicates what your recording does - delete last row of the table until there is only one row left

It turns Off `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation` to make it faster; at the end it turns them back On

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShrinkTable()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")              'Update Sheet Name
        If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            With .ListObjects("RDNPPD")
                While .ListRows.Count > 1               'Delete last row until first
                    .ListRows(.ListRows.Count).Delete
                Wend
            End With
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

---

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

.

`Table` (`ListObject`) structure

---

[image: Table]

Comment: Thank you! I tried both but am receiving the same error message: Delete method of Range class failed. I have the code setup in a module so I can call on it within the sheet for a button. Is this what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Also, thought maybe error was associated with the Autofilter so I wrote the code to turn it off but I'm still getting the error on each of the examples line of code.

Comment: I have worksheets hidden in the spreadsheet but when this part of the code runs, there is no protection on the intended active sheet. I ran the code provided in my question prior to the code you provided. Regardless, with or without my code, the same error message of 'Delete method of Range class failed' appears. I had tried your solutions prior to submitting my question but thought maybe I had something wrong. Not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Ok, just changed .EntireRow.Delete to .EntireRow.Select and all but the first row of the table is selected. What's next?

Comment: I can add a message box for the user to hit Ctrl + -(minus) to delete the selected rows but would prefer to have the code handle it if possible.

Comment: It can become frustrating trying to figure out what’s causing the issue, but I wouldn’t settle for a “manual” approach, no matter how long it would take. Not having access to your table is limiting, but in your place I would go back to basics: can you manually delete the rows? I’m guessing yes, and if so I’d record the deletion to see how Excel is doing it, then the only thing left to do is to clean up the recording (removing all “select” and “activate” lines, and determine how else we can make the first and last row dynamic.

Comment: I added the code created when recording the macro for deleting the selected rows within the table and updated my question. Any thoughts? Oh, and yes, you're correct; I am able to delete all selected rows in the table.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much...it works! And, I learned some new code in the process.

Comment: Glad it finally works! (not sure why is misbehaving - the other versions would have been a bit more efficient)